# Scrollview scrolling is not working on hiding keyboard?

Tags: swift, uiscrollview, swift4, uikeyboard

I have a scrollView with some textFields. The scrolling is fine at the begining but after hiding the keyBoard the scrolling is not working although the contentView is greater than the scrollView. I am using the following functions to show and hide keyBoard:

```
func keyboardWasShown(notification: NSNotification){
        //Need to calculate keyboard exact size due to Apple suggestions
        self.scrollView.isScrollEnabled = true
        var info = notification.userInfo!
        let keyboardSize = (info[UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey] as? NSValue)?.cgRectValue.size
        let contentInsets : UIEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0.0, 0.0, keyboardSize!.height, 0.0)

        self.scrollView.contentInset = contentInsets
        self.scrollView.scrollIndicatorInsets = contentInsets

        var aRect : CGRect = self.view.frame
        aRect.size.height -= keyboardSize!.height
        if let activeField = self.activeField {
            if (!aRect.contains(activeField.frame.origin)){
                self.scrollView.scrollRectToVisible(activeField.frame, animated: true)
            }
        }
    }

func keyboardWillBeHidden(notification: NSNotification){
        //Once keyboard disappears, restore original positions
        var info = notification.userInfo!
        let keyboardSize = (info[UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey] as? NSValue)?.cgRectValue.size
        let contentInsets : UIEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0.0, 0.0, -keyboardSize!.height, 0.0)
        self.scrollView.contentInset = contentInsets
        self.scrollView.scrollIndicatorInsets = contentInsets
        self.view.endEditing(true)
        self.scrollView.isScrollEnabled = true
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Change `UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey` by `UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey` if you want to dismiss the keyboard.

Comment: It didn't work. why do you think that scrolling depends on keyboard user info type?

Comment: because of https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiwindow/keyboard_notification_user_info_keys. You need to check the size of keyboard at the end of the animation